# Dockerfile skip maven dependencies download again and again

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

I have created a `Dockerfile` in a way that **I don't have to download dependencies again and again** with an idea in mind **if any step is not changed**. docker build will not re-run that step

```
COPY pom.xml pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:resolve #here I am expecting it will download all dependencies first time as long as pom is not changed

COPY src src
RUN mvn clean package # This will run, whenever there is a change in code
```

> ****update:****

It is correct it does not run **step2** - but I am expecting it has already downloaded all the dependencies hence `mvn clean package` - step 4 should not download those dependencies again as there is no change in pom file

Comment: you dont have to change anything. As long as you don't change the pom.xml the first two instruction wont run again. You should also see this in the console when building the image. It will report if it takes the layer from cache.

Comment: its an issue with the way you use maven, not with docker itself. You had the same problem locally when ruinning `mvn dependency:resolve` followed by  `mvn clean package`. I don't really know maven well. Maybe try to omit the `clean`. I can imagine it cleans the deps before doing its work.

Comment: You should study this page, in order to get it right https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to change anything in your Dockerfile. Docker will cache `pom.xml` and if it has not been modified since the last build, the `COPY` instruction is skipped.